# WNetAddConnection2 Reconnections fail on subsequent attempts with error 1312

Tags: c#, service, windows-7, samba

**Background**

I have a service that runs on windows 7 (64bit Professional) clients that checks in to a server for updates on a regular interval, it checks for new files to copy down local if they are not present. The way that I have it set up, each file on the server is represented with an object treated as a completely separate entity from the rest.

since the files can come from different locations with different credentials each file is processed as its own transaction. The connection is opened, the file is transferred, the connection is closed. Hundreds of files are processed on each update without a problem.

The problem does not occur until another update runs right behind the first one (within a few minutes of the previous one completing), when this happens the first attempt to connect to the remote resource errors out with an error 1312. The service automatically retries after 30 seconds until it gets a good connection, which takes several minutes, but after that time it goes through and completes without a problem again.

I have tried using both WNetAddConnection2 and WNetUseConnection with the same results, i close the connection using WNetCancelConnection2.

All of this takes place in a BackgroundWorker thread (maybe that is not being cleaned up before the next one starts?)

**Definitions**

```
[DllImport( "Mpr.dll" )]
private static extern int WNetUseConnection( IntPtr hwndOwner, NETRESOURCE lpNetResource, string lpPassword, string lpUserID, int dwFlags, string lpAccessName, string lpBufferSize, string lpResult );

[DllImport( "Mpr.dll" )]
private static extern int WNetAddConnection2( NETRESOURCE lpNetResource, string lpPassword, string lpUsername, int dwFlags );

[DllImport( "Mpr.dll" )]
private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2( string lpName, int dwFlags, bool fForce );

[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
private class NETRESOURCE {
  public int dwScope          = 0;
  public int dwType           = 0;
  public int dwDisplayType    = 0;
  public int dwUsage          = 0;
  public string lpLocalName   = "";
  public string lpRemoteName  = "";
  public string lpComment     = "";
  public string lpProvider    = "";
}
const int RESOURCETYPE_DISK           = 0x00000001;
const int CONNECT_TEMPORARY           = 0x00000004;
```

**Use Examples**

*WNetUseConnection was used for a long time, I just tried WNetAddConnection2 tonight*

```
NETRESOURCE cNetworkResource  = new NETRESOURCE();
cNetworkResource.dwType       = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
cNetworkResource.lpRemoteName = @"\\192.168.5.254\packages";
cNetworkResource.lpLocalName  = "";

//int iReturnValue = WNetUseConnection( IntPtr.Zero, cNetworkResource, "Password", "Username", 0, null, null, null );
int iReturnValue = WNetAddConnection2( cNetworkResource, "Password", "Username", CONNECT_TEMPORARY );
```

And in a different method i close it with

```
int iReturnValue = WNetCancelConnection2( @"\\192.168.5.254\packages", CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE, true );
```

*note: i use variables for path, username, and password not string literals, updated for example only*

The target server is a linux box, and for this example assume the username and password are literally "Username" and "Password" that is the format of them. I have tried adding the server name to the user name such as "192.168.5.254\Username" which causes a 1219 error.

If i reboot the client system it will not error on the first try, which leads me to believe this is something being cached or not properly disposed of on the client side vs the server, I also observe the same behavior with two different linux servers as the remote location with different versions of samba running.

If any more information is needed I can provide it, i'm kind of at my wits-end here so any help is greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Related to the theory I had about the threads not being disposed, as I was testing just now I realized that this probably isn't the case. If the second update happens very quickly after the first one finishes there is no errors, it is only when there is a short pause between them.

Comment: Further testing on times:  < 1 minute after last connection will not error. > 1 minute after will error repeatedly for 10 minutes after which time it will work. Restarting the service does not have an effect. Restarting windows always has an effect.

Comment: Sorry 15 minutes seems to be the upper limit, i didn't account for a 5 minute sleep in the first test.

Comment: My experience suggests that disconnecting from a server by specifying the remote share name does not work as expected.  Annoying as it is, I recommend that you try mapping a drive letter when establishing the connection, so that you can use the drive letter, rather than the share name, to disconnect.

Comment: It might also be possible to use LogonUser (with  `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS`) and impersonation to give each connection its own MPR context.  (I'm not sure.)

Comment: Thanks, i'm hoping not to have to go down that route (mapping) but the outlook isn't very bright at the moment.

Could you expand on your second comment? what is an MPR?

Comment: The MPR (Multiple Provider Router) is the component that figures out which network client needs to be invoked in order to process a given file name.  I only have a vague idea of exactly how everything fits together, it might not really be the MPR that is relevant here.  My thought, however, is that having separate logon sessions might resolve the problem because as I understand things each logon session has its own set of network connections.

Comment: The two caveats are (a) I'm not sure whether or not  `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` actually creates a new logon session or not, and if not, whether whatever it does change would or would not affect network connection caching; and (b) I'm not sure how impersonation affects the use of network connections, which means that it might only work if you actually spawned separate processes to do the work on your behalf.